# How do I change the Android Market email?

Tags: google-play-store

I bought a second-hand mobile.

When I open Market it asks for the password of another account. I don't know how to change the account.

Also, when I go to the Google Play Store and try to download something it is says that the id is missing even when I have signed in to my gmail account.

Comment: Can you please mention your Android version? And what is this Market App? Amazon? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

You can factory reset your phone, in that you can add a new google account.

> - Before you reset your Android One, see options for backing up your data.
> - On your mobile device, open the Settings menu.
> - Under "Personal," touch Backup & reset. You may need to enter your - pattern, PIN, or password.
> - Under "Personal data," touch Factory data reset.
> - Read the information on the screen and touch Reset phone.
> - If you have a screen lock, you'll need to enter your pattern, PIN, or password.
> - When prompted, touch Erase everything to erase all data from your device's internal storage.
> - When your device has finished erasing, select the option to reboot your device.

Now just add new gmail account by going to settings  --> Accounts --> Add New Account. Add your gmail account.

Original Source:

https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/6088915?hl=en

Hope that helps !!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't want to reset your phone. Add a new gmail account by going to settings --> Accounts --> Add New Account. Add your gmail account. Once you are logged in launch your Google playstore app. Click on menu (in left top looks like 3 stacked horizontal lines) you will see old email id, click on that and select your newly added email id. I hope that should do the trick.

EDIT:
To remove your old account launch settings -> select accounts -> select Google -> select the account you want to remove -> click on options at top right (or hardware option key if your phone has one) -> tap on remove account.

Comment: As the "old account" belongs to the previous owner, it might be decent to remove that after having switched to the "new account". I've already upvoted your answer (good alternative) – but to make it even better, maybe you could include details on removing the "old account" as well? Thanks!